Abp generate-proxy -t ng skips api version 2 and always generate version 1
I am using ABP with Angular and have an API that supports multiple versions. Both versions (v1 and v2) show up correctly in Swagger, but when I run abp generate-proxy -t ng, only the endpoints for version 1 are generated in the Angular project. Here are my dependencies:

  "dependencies": {
    "@abp/ng.account": "~8.1.4",
    "@abp/ng.components": "~8.1.4",
    "@abp/ng.core": "~8.1.4",
    "@abp/ng.oauth": "~8.1.4",
    "@abp/ng.identity": "~8.1.4",
    "@abp/ng.setting-management": "~8.1.4",
    "@abp/ng.tenant-management": "~8.1.4",
    "@abp/ng.theme.shared": "~8.1.4",
    "@abp/ng.theme.basic": "~8.1.4",
    "@angular/animations": "~17.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "~17.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~17.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "~17.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~17.3.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~17.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~17.3.0",
    ...
    }
    
  "devDependencies": {
    "@abp/ng.schematics": "~8.1.4",
    ....
    }


Swagger Generate Both Version 1 and 2

Here's an example of one of my versioned API endpoints:
[HttpGet]
[ApiVersion(version: "2.0")]
[Route("api/lookups/v{version:apiVersion}/classifications")]
[Authorize(Policy = DefaultAPIPolicies.PolicyNameForManager)]
public async Task<List<LookupDto>> GetClassificationsAsync_V2()
{
    return await _GetClassificationsQueryHandler.GetAsync();
}


What I've Tried
I confirmed that both versions are present in Swagger.
I tried adjusting the generate-proxy command, but there doesn’t seem to be an option to specify API version.
I also checked for any proxy configuration in appsettings.json and angular.json but didn't find anything restricting it to version 1.
Questions
How can I generate the Angular proxies for both versions' endpoints?
